# jQuery doesn't read CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
// Helper func
init = (obj, id) => {
  return obj.style.split(':')[id]
}

train = (i, o) => {
  iProp = init(i, 0);
  iVal = init(i, 1);
  oProp = init(o, 0);
  oVal = init(o, 1);

  alert($(i.dom).css('color'))
}

train({
  dom: 'p',
  style: 'color:rgb(0, 0, 0)'
}, {
  dom: 'p',
  style: 'color:rgb(0, 50, 65)'
})
```

```css
p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text</p>
```

When I run the code it gives an empty alert, in anWriter Editor it gives an alert 'Undefined'. Why jQuery doesn't see CSS, but I added CSS at the top of the HTML page. Why does it output undefined and how to fix it?

Comment: where is the jQuery code?

Comment: CSS stylesheet  is not the same as element's style object.

Comment: @LelioFaieta his alert is doing a jQuery selector and method call

Comment: @Taplar thanks, didn't notice that :-)

Comment: Are we missing something here, running your snippet I get `rgb(0, 0, 0)`, this is using Chrome.

Comment: This script is not in a document ready.  Snippets on Stack Overflow put the javascript after the markup so a document ready is not needed.  I'm assuming this is part of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think its problem with jQuery or javascript for below reasons:

1. I ran your code and found that the alert is being fired way before the DOM is actually rendered. Please see the screenshot below:

[image: The problem output]

2. Your alert is getting called automatically while your script is getting triggered, which is before the HTML being rendered. So, I moved the script to the bottom of the document and it worked. Please see the screenshot below:
   [image: Expected output]

In a nutshell, I would suggest calling the alert manually when your DOM is actually ready.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Because your DOM wasn't rendered when you call the alert. Try with jquery ready function:

```js
// Helper func
init = (obj, id) => {
  return obj.style.split(':')[id]
}

train = (i, o) => {
  iProp = init(i, 0);
  iVal = init(i, 1);
  oProp = init(o, 0);
  oVal = init(o, 1);
  
  $(function(){
    alert($(i.dom).css('color'));
  });
}

train({
  dom: 'p',
  style: 'color:rgb(0, 0, 0)'
}, {
  dom: 'p',
  style: 'color:rgb(0, 50, 65)'
})
```

```css
p {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Text</p>
```